# Should Secondary Interface use Primary Interface Properties - VBA/VB6

Tags: class, vba, interface, vb6

This is really meant to be a high level best practices question, but I suspect the language I am using may influence the answer (No Constructors).

Is it common to utilize a classes primary properties to process secondary Interface methods?
Or in other words, is it ok for the secondary implementation to have knowledge of the classes internal state and properties?

ie..

```
Class MyClass
Implements MyInterface

Private m_MyState as String

Private Sub MyInterface_DoSecondaryStuff

    Debug.Print m_MyState

End Sub
```

Sorry if this is a noob question, but I don't have the opportunity to program to or create secondary interfaces often.

Comment: Maybe a bad example there but you had to contrive something I suppose.  I don't see any problem with doing this, and in many cases you have no alternative or else the members of the implemented interface become pointless to call anyway.  Few classes are stateless.

Comment: Thanks, Bob. My biggest concern is working with uninitialized properties.  Since VBA does not provide constructors, I think I will make the required properties read only and set them with an init method.

Comment: There is a way to accomplish what a constructor method would do, you create a class factory class that you call to create instances of the target class.  The class factory calls a Friend method of the target class for initilization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely OK. The exception would be if the "secondary implementation" would be better as a separate class of its own.

Comment: Ok thank you Mark, and I appreciate the added tip as well.  In this case, I am using the interface to achieve polymorphism.  But will remember this guideline when trying to determine if an Interface is warranted.